# circle inside a square in Smalltalk

Tags: geometry, smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I draw a circle inside a square in Smalltalk
But I want to reduce it size by 10% so i tried to write it like that:

```
initialize
 | circleWidth circleHeight|
  super initialize.
  self label: ''.
  self borderWidth: 0.
  bounds := 0@0 corner: 70@70.

  circle := CircleMorph new.
  circleWidth := self bounds width*0.9.
  circleHeight := self bounds height*0.9.
  circle bounds: self bounds*0.9.

  circle color: Color paleBuff.
  circle borderWidth: 1.
  self addMorphCentered: circle.


  offColor := Color gray darker.
  onColor := Color gray darker.
  self useSquareCorners.
  self turnOff
```

But the line:
      circle bounds: self bounds*0.9.
has some problem when compiling "Message not understood rectangle >>*"
how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the message `scaleBy: scale` to scale a rectangle.

So

```
circle bounds: self bounds*0.9.
```

becomes:

```
circle bounds: (self bounds scaleBy: 0.9).
```